# How to map json to transfer object but only the fields that have values?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Lets say I have a transfer object like this

```
Class A{
String a;
String b;
String c;
String d;
int e;
int f;
Thing aa;
}
```

Lets say front end wants to patch an item and so they only send us the values they changed as some json like

```
{
"a":"hi"
}
```

In java I map the json to the A class, and 'a' has the right value 'hi', but all the other fields in the transfer object get their default values... I want the class the json mapped into to ONLY have the property 'a'...everything is nullable too so is this possible?

Comment: What library are you using to deserialize JSON to Object? Is it Jackson or something custom?

Comment: We are using Jackson